# Android Studio AVD Emulator error

Tags: android

I'm getting this error while running AVD in Android Studio:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>   Exec format error

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Android SDK Manager and check whether all items are not broken. Try to reinstall Android SDK Tools and Platform Tools.

Comment: Isn't there any other way as reinstalling did not work

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Default Emulator it has several bugs especially android 4.4 emulator use Genymotion emulator for fast development. It has plugin for android studio to debug. works in windows,ubuntu,mac

go to link and download genymotion [Individual](https://www.genymotion.com/)